# how to extract last name?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-2013

**Is there a functoid that specializes in splitting a string based on a delimitter?**

Let's say I have a `Fullname` field that looks like so:

```
Gordon, Liza
Shiksa, Nancy
Shkura, Lola
Sukovich, Matthew
```

**How would I extract last name?**

My desired output would look like this:

```
Gordon
Shiksa
Shkura
Sukovich
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no single functoid that will do this. You have two options:

- Use a script functoid to write a C# method that will parse out the last name
- Use the `String Find`, `Subtraction`, and `String Extract` functoids to get the last name. This method assumes that each input string always has a comma (`,`).

**Option 2 with 3 functoids:**
[image: BizTalk Map]

**String Find Inputs:**

- Input string: `Fullname`
- Search string: `,`

**Subtraction Inputs:**

- Input[0]: `String Find`
- Input[1]: `1`

**String Extract Inputs:**

- Input string: `Fullname`
- Start index: `1`
- End index: `Subtraction`

Connect the output of `String Extract` to your output element. The subtraction is necessary since BizTalk counts string positions starting at 1 and you don't want the comma part of the output.

Comment: the purist way seems to be the way you've elaborated here, using multiple functoids,  however i understand that you can use this with simply 1 scripting functoid as well, my question to you is which way is more preferable and why?

Comment: I think it comes down to personal preference. Once an element starts to require more than 3 or so functoids to make the mapping work, I tend to use scripting functoids since there's much less to look at to understand what's going on. Since this one only needs 3, I'd do it this way. But if you need to handle strings that may or may not contain commas, then I'd go with a scripting functoid to avoid adding a dozen more functoids to the map.